# Deploy application from local git repository

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

This is a two-fold question.

In scenarios where the git repository is not publicly accessible, can I deploy from a local machine (that also runs Ansible) to a remove host using the local copy of the repository on my hard drive (or a copy on the master server, for example)?

If the answer to the previous question is yes, is the git module used for this purpose?

EDIT:

What I've tried thus far:

The dir structure as follows:

```
repo/
|-.git/
|-deploy/
| |-inventory
| |-roles/
| | \-app/
| |   \-main.yml
| \-vagrant.yml
\-src/
```

playbook contains:

```
- name: Clone local application
  git: repo={{ inventory_dir }}/../
       dest=/home/{{ application_name }}/code
```

Deploying this to a vagrant box via SSH results in:

```
fatal: [vagrant]: FAILED! => {
  "changed": false, 
  "cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin path/to/repo", 
  "failed": true, 
  "msg": "Cloning into '/home/app/code'...\nfatal: 
  'path/to/repo' does not appear to be a git repository\nfatal: 
  Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you 
  have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.", 
  ...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible `git` module uses native `git` executable to perform its actions, so you need to proceed like you would do with manual operations.

- Mount the disk containing the Git repository to the target machine.

  This is easily achievable with Vagrant, if you keep the repository under the directory containing `Vagrantfile` (this might be different to your scenario - not sure what you mean by `vagrant.yml`).

  Vagrant mounts this directory by default in `/vagrant` in virtual machine, so to clone a repository you'd use the standard `git` module:

  ```
  - git:
      repo: /vagrant/path/to/source/repository
      dest: /path/to/destination
  ```

  It will clone the repository to `/path/to/destination/repository`.
- Use Ansible [`synchronize` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) to push the repository to the destination machine. If the only reason for cloning is to "deploy application" without pushing back to the original repository, it is sufficient.
- Finally you can share the repository using either of the protocols supported by Git, like SSH, HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, FTPS, rsync; or mount the directory with NFS (this is equivalent of the first method).

Comment: Is the destination on the target host?

Comment: I have a repository on my own computer where I run Ansible, ad I want to deploy that to a remote host.

Comment: Updated the question with some more details.